# dynamically create text areas for jqcleditor (wysiwyg)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

using the `jqcleditor` extension for `Yii WYSIWYG` text editor

I am not able to dynamically generate a new row of 3 text-areas with the `jqcleditor` with `javascript`.

while writing i came on this solution:
call an `ajax` function in my `addRow` function and re-instantiate the `jqclEditor` like I have done in my view right now....is it OK?

kindly let me know

add Row for the same as of now:

```
var tr_string = "<tr id='"+row_counter+"'>\
        <td><textarea name='"+kpa_counter+"' class='kpa'></textarea></td>\
        <td><textarea name='"+kpi_counter+"' class='kpi'></textarea></td>\
        <td><textarea name='"+self_counter+"' class='self'></textarea></td>\
        <td><a onclick='addData(this)' class='btn btn-success' id='"+add_counter+"'>Add</a></td>\
        <td><a onclick='removeData(this)' class='btn btn-danger' id='"+del_counter+"'>Del</a></td>\
        </tr>";
        // console.log(obj)
        $(tr_string).insertAfter($(obj).closest('tr'));
```

Below is the link for the same:

[JqClEditor extension for yii page](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jqcleditor/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instantiated just below it:

```
$(tr_string).insertAfter($(obj).closest('tr'));
        $(".kpa").cleditor({width:200, height:250});
        $(".kpi").cleditor({width:300, height:250});
        $(".self").cleditor({width:400, height:250});
```

[ClEditor Homepage had the answer](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/gettingstarted#Examples)